# Can i remove the WP Media Library filter dropdown (or the row) completely?

Tags: wordpress, filter, modal-dialog, advanced-custom-fields, uploader

I am allowing subscribers to upload images to posts they created with a `ACF` form. Currently it is using the `uploader=wp` WP media library modal.

When clicking on Media Library, for what I am building, there is no need to be able to filter by attachment type, date or a search function. So I want to remove it all, to avoid confusion about useless functions.
I found the `media_view_settings` filter, but only managed to remove the months in the date dropdown and all non-image mime types in the type dropdown.

I could hide it with a jQuery one-liner but would like to have a clean solution, even if its more complicated. According to the source file, there are settings for disabling the toolbar when initializing the modal. Is there a WP filter/hook in which I can reconfigure the default settings / is there any way to remove the row completely by filters/hooks?